# С# Basic. Loops. Выводит на экран квадрат, контур которого отметьте символом "*", размер стороны которого вводит пользователь.

Tags: c#, циклы

Выводит на экран квадрат, контур которого отметьте символом "*", размер стороны которого вводит пользователь.

Какая ошибка в коде? Почему не получается? Поскажите, пожалуйста, решение.
Спасибо!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp24
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of characters: ");
            int characters = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < characters; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < characters; j++)
                {
                    if (i > 0 || j > 0 || i < characters - 1 || j < characters - 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }

                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что код неправильно написан, по сути:

а) Нет перевода строки.

б) Внутренний иф практически совпадает с условием цикла for.

А так... Оно как то так должно быть:

```
for (int i = 0; i < characters; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < characters; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == characters - 1 || j == characters - 1)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!